# How to filter search in Firebase iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can i filter a Firebase query on conditions. I have tried this code

```
    let productsQuery = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Products").queryLimited(toFirst: 10)
    //method 1
    productsQuery.queryEqual(toValue: "Pending", childKey: "Status")
    //method 2
    productsQuery.queryOrdered(byChild: "Status").queryStarting(atValue: "Pending").queryEnding(atValue: "Pending")
```

**But it always returns entire set which is huge** (more than 10k entries)

I want to fetch only the objects in which "Status" = "Pending"

[Backend shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3cbt.png)

I am sure such basic filtering would exist in Firebase. Please let me know.

Comment: Solution :  I wasn't initing the .observeSingleEvent right after the query conditions rather i was initiation the observing with the next line. That was the problem.

Comment: You should do like this which is not mentioned in their docs : `lastProducts.queryOrdered(byChild: "Status").queryEqual(toValue: "Pending").queryLimited(toFirst: 10).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : FIRDataSnapshot) in
    
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine `queryOrdered(byChild:)` and `queryEqual(toValue:)` this way and use `.observeEvent` with it

```
let productsQuery = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Products")
productsQuery.queryOrdered(byChild: "Status").queryEqual(toValue:"Pending")
             .queryLimited(toFirst: 10).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : FIRDataSnapshot) in


})
```

Comment: Still returns entire set.

Comment: @Rijiva Check the edited answer and put `queryLimitedToFirst` at the end, if it still not work show your observing code

Comment: It was a syntactical error. I got it. Basically i had to start the .observeSingleEvent right after the query. I will post the answer here too. Thanks for your effort Nirav

Comment: Sorry nirav... actually that alone didn't work for me. I'd still accept it. Please add the comment i had written under the question. That would help many in the future.